# Windows 10 PC won't sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, troubleshooting, desktop-computer, computer-building

I built my first PC and installed Windows 10 on it. Performs fine except for one recurring issue. Often times, when I try to sleep my system, the peripherals will shut off but other aspects of the computer keep running (e.g., fans, liquid cooler, maybe other things on the mobo). The only way to get it to respond after this happens is to manually turn off the power, restart, and go through the BIOS that gives an error message that says CPU failed to overclock – which is strange because I haven't tried to overclock. Does anyone have a notion as to what might be going wrong here? or have advice on where to look for more info to track the issue to the cause?

Comment: at the very least provide the motherboard make/model. Have you done anything to attempt to resolve this issue on your own? Have you tried updating the BIOS and resetting to defaults?

Comment: Asus Z170-AR. My BIOS should be up to date and default.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to confirm whether your PC really enter sleep mode, turn off display doesn’t mean sleep.

Next, it seems that sleeping a computer is problematic if hibernate is turned on.

Run powercfg -hibernate off in CMD to turn off hibernation.

A Microsoft tool called PsShutdown using the command psshutdown -d -t 0 to put PC into sleep.

PsShutdown v2.52

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown